# Android: Intent.getBooleanArrayExtra(key) returning null

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm making a program that requires transfer of data between `Activities`, I see the boolean array object I'm trying to transfer in `MyIntent.mExtras.mMap`, but when I do,

```
Intent.getBooleanArrayExtra("AnsweredBoolAR")
```

I get `null`. I'm using

```
Intent MyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataSummary.class);
MyIntent.putExtra("AnsweredBoolAR", Answered.toArray());
```

to send my data.

I've used the debugger and the array that I'm putting into the key and value set isn't `null`.

Comment: and the type of `Answered` is .... ? http://ideone.com/qpgyoD

Comment: exactly @Selvin , it depends of the type of that array, because if is a diferent type and you are trying to get as arrayBolean, this will be fail or null. You should check it

Comment: @Selvin Its a boolean arraylist, I didn't see ArrayList<Boolean> as an argument for put extra to send

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `toArray()` method of `ArrayList`, it returns an array of `Object[]` rather than an array of the specific type contained by the `ArrayList`.

When you call `getBooleanArrayExtra(...)` on the `Intent` however, it will be looking specifically for `boolean[]` and returns `null` because it can't find an array of that type.

`ArrayList` implements `Serializable` so you can put the whole thing as it is by using...

```
MyIntent.putExtra("AnsweredBoolAR", Answered);
```

...then when you want to retrieve it from the `Intent` just use the `getSerializableExtra(...)` method of `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks Dude It Worked! :)

Comment: @ToughNoodleIII : Glad it worked for you. I've edited my answer to explain why your original approach didn't work.